# Can you use a function argument directly in a namespace?

Tags: javascript

I have the following function:

```
prevPage: function (store){

    myapp.stores.store.proxy.extraParams = { sendpage: myapp.stores.store.data.items[0].data.currentPage -1 };
    },
```

Which basically modifies the extraParams namespace according to whatever 'store' is entered as an argument in the function, but it doesn't work. I think I am using 'store' wrong in the function definition.

To rephrase, if I define the function as:

```
  prevPage: function (){

    myapp.stores.examplestore.proxy.extraParams = { sendpage:    myapp.stores.store.data.items[0].data.currentPage -1 };
    },
```

It works correctly for the examplestore namespace.

How do I do it so I can have that namespace as a variabl argument in the function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic object property name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamic-object-property-name)

Comment: Hi Felix. When I follow that answer and do this: myapp.stores[store]proxy.extraParams I get an error in the console saying unexpected . found on that line. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but as you now probably already know, you missed a dot after the closing bracket `]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write it this way `myapp.stores[store].proxy.extraParams` where store is a string.